# Modbus slave not communicating with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, modbus

I need help for communicating a Modbus salve to VB.Net.I can read and write data to the slave in VB6 but while trying to read and write data to slave by using VB.net it is not possible.i am attaching the code for the reference.
Waiting for a positive reply.

```
com-com3 in my case
slave id-1
br-19200
databit-8
parity-even
stopbit-1
```

---

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Dim TxMessage As String
    Dim RxMessage As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim spOpen As String
        SerialPort1.Open()
        spOpen = SerialPort1.PortName
        Label1.Text = spOpen
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer_time()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_time()
        Dim CRCWord As Long
        Dim iread As Integer = 7
        Dim ch() As Char = New Char(iread) {}

        TxMessage = Chr(1) & Chr(3) & Chr(0) & Chr(100) & Chr(0) & Chr(1)
        'call the CRC calculation:'
        CRCWord = GetCRC(TxMessage)
        'add the CRC bytes to the message:
        TxMessage = TxMessage & Chr(CRCWord - Int(CRCWord / 256) * 256)
        TxMessage = TxMessage & Chr(Int(CRCWord / 256))
        'clear status text display:
        'clear the receive data buffer:

        SerialPort1.Write(TxMessage)


        RxMessage = ""
        Dim tcnt As Integer = 0
        Do
            'DoEvents()
            tcnt = tcnt + 1
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Loop Until SerialPort1.BytesToRead >= 7 Or tcnt >= 30000
        'RxMessage = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        SerialPort1.Read(ch, 0, iread)

        ''  SerialPort1.Read(ch, 0, 7)
        '' Dim a1 As New StringBuilder
        '' Dim ch1 As Char
        '' For Each ch1 In ch
        '' a1 = a1.Append(ch1)
        '' Next
        'Dim bb As String = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        '' Dim newbuffer As String = a1.ToString
        '' RxMessage = RxMessage & newbuffer

        'RxMessage = SerialPort1.ReadLine
        'Check RxMessage to see if it's complete - the length of each expected reply
        'can be calculated before the TxMessage is sent, when RxMessage contains
        'the expected message length, then reception is complete.
        'Check for valid message CRC:

        If Len(RxMessage) >= 7 Then
            Dim RxCount As Long = Len(RxMessage)
            Dim CRCValue As Long = GetCRC(Mid(RxMessage, 1, RxCount - 2))
            If (CLng(Asc(Mid(RxMessage, RxCount - 1, 1))) + _
                (CLng(Asc(Mid(RxMessage, RxCount, 1))) * 256)) = CRCValue Then
                TextBox1.Text = btod(splitbit(Asc(Mid(RxMessage, 4, 1))) & splitbit(Asc(Mid(RxMessage, 5, 1))))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived


    End Sub

    Private Sub plcwrite()
        Dim CRCWord As Long
        Dim art As String
        Dim varo As Long
        Dim art1 As String
        Dim art2 As String
        art = splitbit(TextBox3.Text)
        varo = Len(art)
        varlen = Strings.Right(art, 8)
        varlen1 = Strings.Left(art, varo - 8)
        art1 = btod(varlen1)
        art2 = btod(varlen)
        TxMessage = Chr(1) & Chr(6) & Chr(0) & Chr(TextBox2.Text) & Chr(art1) & Chr(art2)

        CRCWord = GetCRC(TxMessage)
        'add the CRC bytes to the message:
        TxMessage = TxMessage & Chr(CRCWord - Int(CRCWord / 256) * 256)
        TxMessage = TxMessage & Chr(Int(CRCWord / 256))
        'clear status text display:
        'clear the receive data buffer:
        RxMessage = ""

        'send the message out the COM port:
        Dim tcnt As Integer
        tcnt = 0
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
            tcnt = tcnt + 1
        Loop Until SerialPort1.BytesToRead >= 7 Or tcnt >= 30000
        Dim a1 As Integer
        a1 = Len(TxMessage)
        SerialPort1.Write(TxMessage, 0, a1)
        SerialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer()

        MsgBox("Controller Setting update")
    End Sub
```

Comment: What errors you are getting? use modbus poll or hyper terminal to see the message and byte sequence.